# Is it necessary to add a comma in this sentence “Pumas are large, cat-like animals which are found in America. ”

Tags: word-usage, commas

If we delete the comma between "large" and "cat-like",does it make a difference?

Comment: Should probably be “...that are found...”; or just “...animals found in America.”

Comment: Another similar question: [Is there a rule for using commas with multiple adjectives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385578/is-there-a-rule-for-using-commas-with-multiple-adjectives)

Comment: It makes little difference to the puma...

Comment: Civets are cat-like. Pumas *are* cats. You wouldn't describe them as cat-like.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule saying:  If you can add "and", then use a comma.

In this example, you can't add "and".
"We stayed at an expensive summer resort"