# Last comma in a list of comma-separated adjectives

Tags: adjectives, commas

"Big, white, mountain goat."
"Fast, red, Japanese car"

Should there be a comma before "mountain" and before "Japanese"? Adjectives in a list are separated by commas in English, but somehow this last comma seems wrong to me. I've seen sentences with and without this comma. Can someone clarify this for me?

I apologize if my question is unclear, I'm not a native English speaker. I'd appreciate edits for clarity.

Comment: Generally you shouldn't use commas between adjectives in noun phrases. One of the reasons is that the intonation between adjectives isn't really a comma intonation; another reason is that putting a comma right before the noun (because there is the same intonation) makes it look wrong to many people. _Big white mountain goat_ and _fast red Japanese car_ don't need commas.

Comment: No, you don't need a comma before the last adjective. Look here for some examples http://www.chompchomp.com/handouts/commatip06.pdf

Comment: 'Adjectives in a list are separated by commas in English' is woefully imprecise. There are threads that should be referenced such as [Is there a rule for using commas with multiple adjectives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385578/is-there-a-rule-for-using-commas-with-multiple-adjectives) and [Do I need to use a comma between two adjectives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344091/do-i-need-to-use-a-comma-between-two-adjectives/344093#344093). The latter looks at 'cumulative and coordinate adjective' strings.

Comment: This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

Comment: _Mountain_ is not an adjective. _Mountain goat_ is a compound noun, so the last adjective in that example is _white_. It’s nearly always incorrect to separate a noun from an immediately preceding adjective that modifies it. The car example is fine as written (though it would be more common to get rid of one or more of the commas), but the goat example is unequivocally mispunctuated.